# Akka Stream emitting random amount of items

Tags: kotlin, akka

I have a file that consists of 66564 lines that I am splitting into each lines. I will need to group those lines together based on a line that indicates the end of a record. I am intending to use `splitAfter` to do this, but for now I am already stuck with this:

```
    val numLines = AtomicLong(0)
    FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(file))
            .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString.fromString("\n"), Int.MAX_VALUE, true))
            .map { it.decodeString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) }
            .map {
                numLines.incrementAndGet()
                it
            }
            .to(Sink.ignore())
            .run(materializer)
            .toCompletableFuture()
            .get()

    println(numLines.get())
```

I was expecting this to return the number of lines (66564), however it returns different values on each run (for the same file). Values are normally between 64000 and 66000.

I am sure it is some small thing, but I have been looking at this for hours now and I just dont understand why it creates random results...

Comment: I dont really feel like this is the proper answer - hence the comment - but changing the sink to anything but `Sink.ignore` (for example `Sink.last()`) will actually cause it to consistently read everything...